# Ender 3 v2 temp fluctuations every 10 minutes or so

Tags: creality-ender-3, temperature, thermal-runaway

I have an Ender 3 v2 that will fluctuate the hotend temperature every 10 minutes or so and eventually causing thermal runaway. I have tried the PID auto-tune a few times and it seems to solve it for a couple of days. Any idea what’s going on?

[image: Screenshot of OctoPrint's temperature graph]

Today I ran the PID auto-tune again a few times trying to figure out the issue. Now when I heat the hotend to 220 °C it holds perfectly for about 15 minutes then drops and goes into thermal runaway shutdown. I heated the hotend while the printer was not printing to eliminate a bad electrical connection as the issue. Is this maybe a thermistor issue?

Comment: Have you solver this issue yet? Have you checked for loose hotend thermistor?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was the beginning of the hot end thermistor failing. I took the opportunity to upgrade to an all metal hot end. That was the start of a nightmare that lead to the failure of my mainboard. But it is working now and no temp issues after several months and many prints.